# Javascript link help creating cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have create some javascript links. But on hover there is no cursor.

How do I create a cursor for my javascript links? Link the cursor that appears on normal links.

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

var google = 'www.google.com';
<% end %>
function www(url) { window.open(url);}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using css.

```
.jsLink{cursor:pointer;}
```

Where jsLink is classname of your Javascript link.

I hope I got the syntax right since I have very limited ways of checking from my phone

Hope it is any use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aa6Vc/

It contains div with link attached and cursor on it.

Comment: How do I make it something like this function www(url) { window.open(url);}?

Comment: Don't understand you. Just define it or you want to know something else?

Comment: I want to make some links like <img onclick="javascript:www(google);" /> With your solution then I do need to know every ID of the links I want to create

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Aa6Vc/3/ You will need to place your redirect function in the <head> section

Answer (score 0):

Use real links. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)